# Cauchy integrals over a line

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

Can we generalize the Cauchy integral formula from a circle to a line? Since for real integrals, the following types of improper integrals do not converge, is it correct or not that for $z\notin \mathbb{R}$,

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t-z}dt=2\pi i,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt=2\pi i f(z)
\end{equation}
for $f$ holomorphic?

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{u(t)}{t-z}dt=Re(2\pi i f(z))=-2\pi v(z),
\end{equation}
for $u$ harmonic and $v$ toe harmonic conjugate  of $u$?

Comment: Yes we can, it's called the [Schwarz Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula). You do however need an additional constraint on $u(t)$, ie that it decreases fast enough an $|t|\rightarrow \infty$